# How to back up my Ubuntu data when I forget my encrypted filesystem password?

Tags: 14.04, encryption, password-recovery

I need to make a backup of my computer but my filesystem is encrypted and my password is incorrect. How can I do this?

*Update:* My guest account is working now. Can I backup my administrator account data?

Comment: Normal user account password or did you encrypt your disk?

Comment: RockDoctor had a quick easy solution.  (http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/ubuntu-63/unable-to-get-past-login-screen-passwords-not-recognized-4175440904/#post4846934)

Comment: @SteveR. That forum post doesn't seem to mention an encrypted filesystem; those steps won't work unless you can decrypt the filesystem first.

Comment: Ubuntu uses real encryption -- that is, it's secure and the only way to decrypt it is if you have the correct password. Think about it -- if you could back up your data without the correct password, so could *anyone* with access to your computer! For that reason, it is not possible to do what you're asking. I wish you luck in remembering your password.

Answer (score 2):

It is completely impossible to recover encrypted files if you forget your password. Unlike the password to an account, which can be reset, if you forget the password to an encrypted filesystem, the files are lost forever.

Atleast, that seems to be the case.